# is @Singleton in dagger 2 thread safe?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-safety, dagger-2

I'm trying to move everything in my app away from singletons, because I've been made aware that it's a bad programming practice, with that said, I'm looking into implementing Dagger 2 dependency injection. And I'm wondering, when you do @Singleton in Dagger 2 is that thread synchronized? if not how can I synchronize it, so I don't get any strange data anomalies from multiple threads touching the same things.

When I was creating singletons before I'd do something like this:

```
public class SomeSinglton {
    private static ClassName sInstance;

    private SomeSinglton () {
    }

    public static synchronized ClassName getInstance() {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            sInstance = new ClassName();
        }
        return sInstance;
    }
```

is the Dagger 2 @Singleton equivalent as far as being synchronized?

Comment: you sure that method needs to be sync, and not sIntance? Maybe i'm wrong, but based on my expirience i would say that sync is not in a right place, but if i'm wrong, i want to know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Artem Zinnatullin mentioned in his answer - instance creation of @Singleton classes is thread safe in Dagger.

But if you are going to touch that singleton from different theads you must make it thread safe by yourself. Otherwise Dagger won't help you.

Usually, @Singleton annotation should mean for other developers that such class can be used from different threads.

Comment: Thank you. is that something I should implement in the Module or in the class the Module is generating?

Comment: This should be related directly to the class. I recommend you to read something about java concurrency and how to make thread safe code. Synchronize a whole class is usually a bad idea.

Comment: This is not true, `@SIngleton`s are thread safe in Dagger 2, see my answer below.

Comment: Actually I meant not instance creation of a class, but using. Despite the fact that creation is thread safe, using that instance from several threads is still not thread safe. I'll modify my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, got it, sure, no magic, object must be thread safe if you're sharing it to multiple threads.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, `@Singleton`s in Dagger 2 are thread safe with double checked locking, same in Dagger 1. See [`ScopedProvider`](https://github.com/google/dagger/blob/master/core/src/main/java/dagger/internal/ScopedProvider.java).

Answer (score -2):

Loot at [this site](http://www.journaldev.com/1377/java-singleton-design-pattern-best-practices-with-examples). There are different approaches to implement Singleton, among them  ThreadSafeSingleton

Comment: This should be a comment. Other than the link, it provides no true answer to the question.

Answer (score -3):

There's nothing wrong with singletons.  But this is a *better* implementation.

```
public class SomeSinglton {
    private static ClassName sInstance = new SomeSinglton();

    private SomeSinglton () {
    }

    public static ClassName getInstance() {
        return sInstance;
    }
```

There's an implicit synchronization when the static field `sInstance` is initalized.

Comment: I don't think this answers my question... I'm referring to dependency injection with the Dagger 2 library. And I've now read in too many places that singletons are bad... they are bad because they are very hard to Unite Test, and because they tightly couple components. Also I'm pretty sure your code in that example is not thread safe. It's not synchronized. I think that would cause a lot of issues in a multithreaded app.

Comment: I'll bet that library implemented it correctly. And I assure you that my impl is correct and *better* :) trust me.

Comment: As to whether singletons are bad - have you personally got into any problem with your singletons? An opinion does not become more correct if its repeated a million times; unfortunately that happens a lot in our industry.

Comment: Could you explain how your implementation is better? and Yes I have gotten into trouble with Singletons. I've used them in an android app. They have caused a lot of odd state issues, but they also are really hard to test. I've started to unite test my app and realized it's almost impossible with Singletons. I do think you are right though that Singletons aren't inherently bad, but I do think they promote lazy programming at least in my case that is true.

Comment: thank you for clarifying your implementation. That's good to know. I had no idea that there was an implied synchronization.

Comment: "odd state issues" are application logic bugs; I doubt a framework can help that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77819/discussion-between-alexw-h-b-and-bayou-io).

Comment: Your example is lacking of a very important detail: the final keyword on the sInstance static member. As whether your implementation is "better", one might argue that achieving the singleton pattern in this way makes really hard to unit test components that depend on the singleton class.